# Winterbash 2015 participation

Tags: discussion, community, winterbash-2015

Last year, TeX.SE opted out of participating in [Winterbash 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/). [Winterbash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) will [begin shortly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270189/168244) (December 14th, 2015 GMT). Are you interested to have TeX.SE join this year? The mods need to let SE know by December 10th so vote early.

### More on the Winterbash

Winter Bash is a fun, lighthearted event SE runs every year as a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make the communities awesome. It's open to any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate.

During Winter Bash, users earn virtual hats by completing certain tasks. They're sort of like badges, but they're more visible and less permanent. Hats can be "worn" on users' avatars just about anywhere avatars show up on the network. Here's an example of what some hats looked like last year, taken from the network leaderboard:

[image]

Of course, SE is rolling out an all-new assortment of hats for this year's event, as they have in the past.

### The Details

This year's event will start on 14 December 2015 and run up to and including 03 January 2016. Users will be able to see all the hats they've earned on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com. That site will also have an FAQ to explain how things work.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Comment: Please consider casting your vote below. Upvote = Yes please! Downvote = No thanks.

Comment: Note to Paulo: Downvoting here is not a crime! :)

Comment: @yo': ♥♥♥♥ `:)`

Comment: So this comes down to whether or not you like [Team Fortress 2](http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ss/srends/87197a.jpg)...

Comment: @Tom: LOLOLOLOL

Comment: Hope my edit is helpful.

Comment: @StrongBad: Thanks for the addition!

Comment: There's definitely worse than to wear a (virtual) funny hat for a limited period of time ;-)

Comment: @TomBombadil I believe you can only wear one hat at a time....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Upvote = Yes! Please sign us up for hats!

Downvote = No thank you, I'd rather enjoy a regular day at the office.

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking that people still have the ability to opt in/out? Just if the site opts out, people don't have the choice of opting in?

Comment: @cfr that is the case. I edited in some/most of the info from the email sent to SE mods about the process.