# Winterbash 2016 participation

Tags: discussion, community, winterbash

[Last year](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6406/5764), TeX.SE joined in on Winterbash 2015. Winterbash 2016 is around the corner and sites will soon have the option of opting in/out. In order to solicit opinion from the community, please cast your vote in the answer below.

### More on the Winterbash

Winter Bash is a fun, lighthearted event SE runs every year as a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make the communities awesome. It's open to any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate.

During Winter Bash, users earn virtual hats by completing certain tasks. They're sort of like badges, but they're more visible and less permanent. Hats can be "worn" on users' avatars just about anywhere avatars show up on the network. Here's an example of what some hats looked like last year, taken from [the network leaderboard](http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015):

[image]

Of course, SE is rolling out an all-new assortment of hats for this year's event, as they have in the past.

### The Details

This year's event will [start December 19th, 2016 and run through January 8th, 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287412/168244). Users will be able to see all the hats they've earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have an FAQ to explain how things work.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Comment: The image looks like it’s two years old, though. I’m pretty positive the pirate hat was not available in 2015.

Comment: @Jan: 'tis true, me mate-y.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Upvote = Yes! Please sign us up for hats!

Downvote = No thank you, I'd rather enjoy a regular day at the office.

Comment: What if I don't care as I disable these things? Shall I vote -1?

Comment: @yo': If you don't care, then you don't have to vote; that's what I think.

Comment: HATS, SILLY HATS, YAAAAAY!

Comment: It would be interesting to know the +/- split for those who don't have sufficient rep to disaggregate the total. Not sure how that's most easily done, though.

Comment: Final participation, as of Dec 19 - [start of Winterbash 2016](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287412/168244): +35 / -5 = +30