# A proposal to include a duck in our background image

Tags: discussion, ducks

Nowadays, TeX and friends are far beyond of just academic usage. I would like to propose the inclusion of a greyscale duck (courtesy of `tikzducks`) in our background image. This is the current image:

[image: Quack]

The following image is a concept sketch. Note how graceful the duck is when compared to the other elements.

[image: Quack]

So, dear community, should we go one step further towards quackiness? `:)`

Comment: This is a great way to demonstrate the versatilely of tex!

Comment: The placement seems like it would get hidden behind the top bar.

Comment: @samcarter: How does one interpret the two answers? For example, what does an upvote on the "No" answer imply compared to a downvote on the same answer. Similarly for the "Yes" answer. It seems possible to consolidate them into one: Upvote = support; downvote = not.

Comment: @Werner Well, at the current vote count, do the downvotes really matter?  I guess two scenarios are possible a) a user upvotes one of the answers and nothing else b) a user upvotes one of the answers and downvotes the other (I think downvoting without upvoting is not very likely). So probably comparing the upvotes of both answers would be the fairest....

Comment: @PauloCereda What is your opinion to @ Werners comment?

Comment: @samcarter: [Here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6975/5764) is a related poll done for Winterbash 2016.

Comment: @Werner Offtopic: do you know if tex.stackexchange will participate in this years bash?

Comment: @samcarter: I didn't pose the question, but last year's feedback seemed positive. Based on [a discussion on The Tavern on Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6521693#6521693) it is currently set as an "opt out" option. That is, it is assumed the site is in unless the mods mention otherwise.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for this information! Back to the topic: I believe comparing the upvotes of both answers should in first order approximation be the same as comparing up/down of a single answer.

Comment: The No question is really a biased question, since it requires you to vote no on the basis of silliness. But there are certainly other reasons why one might vote no, and so this might discourage no voters.

Comment: I actually would prefer a marmot instead of the duck, or, even better, a marmot and a duck. ;-)

Comment: I agree with @AlanMunn. I don't think the votes will tell you anything much. Especially if you take account of the fact that there are probably a high number of passers-by who will upvote any post with a fun image, regardless of content. Either both answers should have a fun image or neither. And either they should both be reason specific or they should neither be. Anyway, why not witches, donkeys or cats?

Comment: There is typo in the question. It should be "towards quackiness".

Comment: I also think the two possible answers are totally misleading. There should be only one possible answer. Upvote it if you like the proposition, downvote if you don't agree.

Comment: At this point, I have no idea of what to do with this question! `:)`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And then there were three ... :(.

Comment: I think this question is valid as it pertains to the (main) site. However, design considerations like this will definitely be low on the priority list for the developers as they have bigger ducks to fry. Regardless, for any change of meaningful discussion (and support or not), the dual answers should be merged into one. Preferably, they should be deleted and a new one should be made.

Comment: @cfr: I meant only one answer concerning the 'poll' count. Of course others may add answers as well.

Comment: I think this is riduckulous!!

Comment: this question or even the idea is just an example of the computer bug that comes after prolongued periods of computer usage with nothing better to do. Gosh, I sound grumpy ;)

Comment: This image shows much better the power of TeX as a graphics program: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/56233

Comment: @musarithmia I want it in the background!!!!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Attractive though the addition of a duck is, I am not in favour of this proposal. However, I am not opposed on the grounds that it is 'too silly'. I am opposed on the grounds that it would institutionalise what is essentially an 'in joke' and thereby symbolise a kind of exclusivity which I would not like to see the site embrace.

I realise that, in practice, people are unlikely to even notice the duck. However, I think that the image is a statement about the community and this community's attitude to visitors, including both regular members, newbies and passers-by.

I may not be explaining this objection very well and I do not expect this post to be popular. I post it because, after considerable thought, I concluded that *somebody* should say it. Unfortunately, nobody else has stepped up, so the somebody happens to be me.

Comment: +1 I agree exactly with this sentiment.

Comment: Clearly my responses don't help, so I'll delete them. Maybe @AlanMunn can explain it better.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I share cfr's views on this, because it adds a particular element related primarily to a particular person created by a particular package. I am one of many who counts Paulo as a good friend but I think that this addition has the potential to be perceived differently by people who are not among the usual residents of the chat, which are a very small minority of the users of the site.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this insightful view, I agree with you. `:)` I think this is a strong and definitive case. Thanks for being the voice of reason amongst we wacky people. `:)`

Comment: The current background shows mathematics, the inscription of the ring, something chemical and a sphere (no quite sure what it represents). Imho some graphic fits well. I also think that something which is a bit of a joke fits well. Such internal jokes glue a society together. They are in carneval, in the ig nobel prize,  in the winterbash and in lots of other traditions around the world.

Comment: @PauloCereda Thank you for understanding. I love the ducks and I like the 'in jokes', too. I agree with Ulrike that such traditions bind communities. I just feel that the official image of the site needs to reflect our community's attitude to everyone and not contain elements designed to speak specifically to existing members. I'm not sure I did a good job explaining this, but I'm glad that you understood, as the OP. :-)

Comment: @PauloCereda I hope I'm not altogether un-wacky, too!

Comment: @cfr: A merry quack to you from the resident hwyaden! `:)`

Comment: Hm. I wonder if "One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them," really reflects out community's attitude to everyone. It is a rather unfriendly text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If that seems relevant, I've clearly not explained very well. See Alan Munn's attempt above. I deleted my earlier follow-up comments attempting to explain further, because they clearly didn't help at all.

Comment: @cfr I was more musing to myself if one should suggest to remove the text. But beside this I think it is relevant but too long for a comment. If you are really interested in discussing this you could open a chat room.

Comment: @AlanMunn, cfr, what musarithmia wrote in her/his comment to the question could be a valid alternative

Answer (score 59):

## Yes, definitely!

[image]

Answer (score 13):

## Everybody can decide for themselves

Luckily there are browser addons which can exchange the default background image by a version including the duck, so every user can decide if he/she wants to use one of these addons to have a duck in the background image.

Addons capable to do the image exchange are for example `stylish` or from the `greasemonky`/`Tampermonkey` family.

Please feel free to add instructions for more browser/addon combinations!

## Instructions for firefox with greasemonkey

1. Install greasemonkey addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
2. add a new user script via `tools->greasmonkey->New User Script...`
   [image]
3. In the following dialogue, choose a name of your choice and add

   ```
   https://tex.stackexchange.com/*
   http://tex.stackexchange.com/*
   https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/*
   http://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/*
   ```

   to the `Included Pages` field.
4. Now click on `Edit this User Script` and copy & paste the following code:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name _TeX SE, Swap header background
   // @match *://tex.stackexchange.com/*
   // @grant GM_addStyle
   // @run-at document-start
   // ==/UserScript==

   GM_addStyle ( `
   #header {
   background: transparent url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfSC.png') no-repeat 50% -25px !important;
   }
   ` );
   ```
5. Save, close and consider upvoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/19392142/2777074 as this answer made the above script possible
6. enjoy the duck

[image]

## Instructions for Opera with `Custom Style Script`

(from the [comment by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7475/a-proposal-to-include-a-duck-in-our-background-image/7482?noredirect=1#comment22359_7482))

1. Install the `Custom Style Script` addon: https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/custom-style-script/?display=en
2. add

   ```
   #header {
   background: transparent url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfSC.png') no-repeat 50% -25px !important;
   }
   ```

   as a css rule

Comment: On opera I installed the "Custom Style Script" add-on (https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/custom-style-script/?display=en) and added the `#header` style as a css rule.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comment. I tried to add it to the answer, please feel free to edit.

Comment: I'm wondering why a user downvoted even this answer!

Answer (score 4):

## No way, this is far too silly!

Comment: Is it allowed to down vote here?

Comment: @Sigur 3 people have already done it (+4-3=+1).

Comment: @CarLaTeX, nice. Since I like the idea, I dislike the *No way* answer. So, -1!

Comment: @Sigur Paulo will be happy :):):)