# What is the point of the ducks tag in non meta tex

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, ducks

As far as I can tell there's only ever been one post utilizing the `ducks` tag without the `tikzducks` tag. might they not just as well be merged? or would it be acceptable for me to start asking about duck-trivia on TeX.Se as long as I use the `ducks` tag?
Will the site slowly turn into a duck encyclopedia?

Comment: I am missing `pstricksducks` and `metapostducks` and `svgducks` and `epsducks` as well...

Comment: Since I removed all my comments to Henri Menke's answer it may be unclear, but I _completely agree_ to remove the `duck` tag from the main site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, the [ducks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ducks) tag is quite pointless outside of Meta.  Since ducks are sort of an inside joke on TeX.SX, I have retagged all the [ducks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ducks) questions (following the same reasoning as in [A proposal to include a duck in our background image](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7480)).

Comment: @CarLaTeX You have 63 votes in favour and 35 against the proposal **out of a total of 126k users**.  That's hardly democratic.  And only because a few people who visit this site very frequently have an inside joke, does not justify forcing it onto anyone else.  I completely agree with cfr here.

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's quite a difference because that is on Meta which is far less outward facing than the main site.  As you might notice, I didn't touch the [tag:ducks] tag on Meta.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I personally wouldn't mind but you'd have to ask the site devs if it's possible to have different pictures for main and meta.

Comment: @CarLaTeX with the amount of [changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes?cb=1) coming to SO I surely hope they'll allow different top bars on meta and main (I don't know though)

Comment: What's with `ducksay` and the upcoming `duckuments` packages? They don't have their own tags as far as I know.

Comment: @CarLaTeX yes, there is, just uploaded it to CTAN but it's not accepted yet. You can take a look [on github](https://github.com/Skillmon/ltx_duckuments) and a small example of use [here on TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419751). Sadly I just recognize, that I should have named it differently, so that one can create a `duckument` class.

Comment: @CarLaTeX the package came late compared to the initial answer. Maybe you upvoted the initial one, but the edit was afterwards.

Comment: @Skillmon: I wonder how many clones of your github repository will appear ;-)

Comment: @Skillmon Fantastic! Never again the boring `example-image`, from now on example images will be fun!

Comment: I used to like ducks but then some duck apologists started flooding my favourite internet board with childish duck memes and now I can't stand them anymore.  Also please move this discussion to chat.  I keep on getting notified.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry. I'm afraid I rather lost track of the fact that this was discussion on your post. And I really, really, really hope this doesn't get dragged up again. (I know it is my fault for rising to it.)

Answer (score 6):

This is too long for a comment, but it's meta anyway. `:)`

I remember when I saw this question in our main site: [LaTeX template for the journal "Blood"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153389/latex-template-for-the-journal-blood)

Almost instinctively, and having myself enough reputation, I decided to lighten up the mood and did the following:

[image: Vampires]

I giggled for almost 3 minutes (*hee hee vampires*), but then later I realized it wouldn't be fair to the community, as I was misusing the tagging system (which serves a very important purpose) for a something other than keeping organisation and classifying topics of interest. Three minutes later, there was my edit once again:

[image: No more vampires]

*(in the meantime, Tom had correctly added the [journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal) tag to the question)*

I think we (the community) owe a great deal to fantastic people who devoted their online time to tagging questions, in particular (to name one) Thomas Titz (aka [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)). So keeping the system in good health is important for new users and even for us regulars, for making information easily searchable and honour the efforts of our peers to make knowledge reachable.

I, of all users here, love the silliness in our duck-related jokes, but I think sometimes we need to refrain ourselves of a too bold move. Tagging is perhaps one of few dogmatic entities around, so it's better to not poke it.

In meta, well... meta is a different thing. `:)`

Comment: In the comments I deleted there was also the one that I completely agree to remove the `duck` tag on the main site, of course.

Comment: You could have combined the Duck and the Vampire aspect with `Count Duckula` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ooh das Vampirente