# Sign error in Eulers formula in header on front page?

Tags: discussion

**Edit**:
Turns out it's (maybe) not a sign error, but the vertical line in the plus might be hidden by the parenthesis in the background. It still appears like an error!

I noticed this today, on the site header (bottom right of the TeX-logo, both on meta and the main site):

[image]

Which I read to say

[image]

and it is [wrong](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex+(cos(y)+%2B+i+sin(y))+%3D+e%5E(x-+i+y)). The [correct expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(x-+i+y)+%3D+e%5Ex+(cos(y)+-+i+sin(y))) I believe to be $\cos(-y) + i \sin(-y)$ which simplifies to

[image]

My suggestion would be either to change exp(x-i y) to the more conventional

[image]

(or at least insert the minus sign in the right hand side).

Comment: I have a few problems with my internet connection, so could be my side: the images don't work.

Comment: The images show up here, but the two last ones are TeX on transparent background, which makes them "invisible" on the link.

Comment: You are right but isn't there a `+` in the exponential? At least I see a dim vertical bar in the middle of the `-`. My interpretation is that this is (just) a rendering issue.

Comment: Hummm. If I stare at it long enough, the vertical bar appears. However if I look away and look back at it quickly it's gone again x')

Comment: But it definitely *looks* like a sign error when not zoomed in like crazy, and should still be fixed?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman In case this bothers you and you'd like to replace the image for yourself: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7482/36296

Comment: @samcarter I’m soo getting a duck!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Just place the duck over the plus/minus sign and the problem is solved :)

Comment: @samcarter I think it is really time for a new package: `duckmath` ;-) This will make math the most popular subject in schools. ;-) And there would be a new sign: `\semiplus`.

Comment: So guys, completely off-topic: My machine refuses to find i.stack.imgur.com. Did anyone had this issue before? No images right here.

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman The problem disappeared. No idea what was going on.

Comment: Related: [Site Design Ideas (updated with mockup)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/638/5764)

Comment: I think there is no vertical bar. It is something behind it that overlaps which is containing a `\rangle`, but if I tilt my screen the difference in opacity is clearly visible. I think you're right!

Comment: @Johannes_B the leading `i` suggests that your link is imaginary.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to upvote comments based on humor. But THIS ^^

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman upvoting comments based on humor is fine as far as I know. The most upvoted comments of all time contain a gem that reads like this "googling crazy latex stuff didn't turn out as expected" or something like that. And since this is meta the rules shouldn't be that strict I think.

Comment: @Skillmon https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm#comment57793_29402

Comment: @samcarter thank you for posting the link. I was too lazy :)

Comment: Here is a link to the background image containing the design components: [image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/sites/tex/img/bg-graph-top.png)

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure... Seriously, I'm not sure. Below is an aggressive filtering. I think it could be just anti-aliasing (hinting) fail.

[image]

Comment: related image: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/648/36296

Comment: I agree with this! It's there maybe. If you look at it long enough, you can see it, but if you look away and right back at it, it disappears. It's an illution! Or as @marmot suggested, a `\semiplus`.

Comment: @samcarter Yes, in the link you share one can clearly see it is a real plus, not just a `\semiplus` ;-)

Comment: BUT: can it be fixed by some awesome person? <3

Comment: @Andreas I afraid that even if we insisted it's a bug, it's too minor to be fixed, given the overall graphic design backlog of SE sites (AFAIK, there're still sites waiting for their design to be made).

Answer (score 2):

TeX is not limited to typesetting correct maths beautifully.

It is equally capable of typesetting incorrect maths beautifully.

Hence, even if the equation is actually incorrect, it still reflects the purpose of the site as well as if it was correct.

If the equation appeared incorrect on maths SE or if the equation here looked ugly, whether correct or not, that would be quite a different kettle of porridge.

But it doesn't and it isn't, so it's not.

Comment: Incorrect maths is ugly!

Comment: Then why not use Eulers identity which is scientifically proven to be the most beautiful equation in the world?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman No it isn't! Maybe you read the wrong maths. So 'most beautiful equation' = 'least ugly equation'? Anyway, where's the challenge in typesetting the most beautiful one? The challenge is to typeset the most ugly beautifully!

Comment: First: see [page 3](https://books.google.no/books?id=GvSg5HQ7WPcC&pg=PA2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) here. Also google [most beautiful equation](https://www.google.no/search?q=most+beautiful+equation). Second: on the page it's not actually Eulers identity, but Eulers formula! They differ!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: that’s not a very scientific approach now, is it?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Why would you expect me to take a scientific approach? Why think a scientific approach to beauty is appropriate or even possible?

Comment: I note that as many people down-voted as up-voted this. Presumably/possibly one down-voter has commented. What about the rest? (Just curious - this is Meta and the usual guidelines don't apply, so this isn't a gripe.)

Comment: I wish there was another counter, though, which people could use to indicate whether they thought a post was serious or not. That would be of greater interest here than whether people agree or not. [Of course, the most beautiful maths is correct. It does not follow that all incorrect maths is ugly, that no incorrect maths is beautiful or that all correct maths is beautiful.]

Comment: I don’t down vote posts like this just because I disagree. You have a valid point, and I actually upvoted your post :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman On Meta, downvote just means disagree, I think. Anyway, I didn't particularly think you had - just that that would account for at most one of the down-votes. Thanks for the up-vote, though: negated one of the down-votes :-).

Comment: We ducks are very good at mathematics, specially wrong mathematics. `:)`